# Why does my new component not display in a null layout manager?

Tags: java, swing, null-layout-manager

There is a panel in a `JFrame` called a `WatchPanel extends JPanel` which uses a `GroupLayout` and contains a `WatchListPanel extends JPanel`.  The `WatchListPanel` uses a `null` `LayoutManager` and contains several instances of `WatchItemPanel extends JPanel`.  The `WatchItemPanel` lays out its contents with a `GridBagLayout`.

When I load up the frame and instantiate the `WatchPanel`, I pre-load the `WatchListPanel` with three `WatchItemPanel` instances with data.  These work fine.  My implementation allows these to be reordered by dragging and dropping (hence the `null` layout), and that works as well.  On the `WatchPanel` is a button to add a new watch, which pops up a new panel in its own `JFrame` where a watch can be added.  When the "Save" button is pressed on this new panel, it adds the new watch to the `WatchPanel`, which trickles down into the `WatchListPanel` and closes the `JFrame` for adding a new watch.

The problem is that when this new `WatchItemPanel` is added, it doesn't get painted unless I resize the `JFrame` containing the `WatchPanel`.  I can interact with it through drag-n-drop.  I can even drag that specific panel - but it's blank.  The moment I resize the `WatchPanel`, it appears and is painted correctly.

Now, I have overridden the `setBounds` method on `WatchListPanel` to call `setSize` and `repaint` on each of the `WatchItemPanel` instances in the list, but I am calling `setBounds` and `repaint` on the new `WatchItemPanel` already as I add it.  I have tried adding `repaint` and `invalidate` calls in every conceivable place thinking maybe I missed something, but no luck.  I absolutely have added the `WatchItemPanel` to the `WatchListPanel` and called `setBounds`, `setVisible(true)`, and `repaint` on the new panel.

Here are the `addWatch` and `updatePositions` methods on the `WatchListPanel`:

```
public void addWatch(Watch watch) {
    WatchItemPanel watchPanel = new WatchItemPanel(watch);
    synchronized (this.watches) {
        this.watches.add(watch);
    }
    this.watchPanels.put(watch, watchPanel);
    this.add(watchPanel);
    watchPanel.setOpaque(false);
    watchPanel.setForeground(this.getForeground());
    watchPanel.setBackground(this.getBackground());
    watchPanel.setVisible(true);
    watchPanel.setSize(this.getWidth(), WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT);
    for (MouseListener l: this.mouseListeners)
        watchPanel.addMouseListener(l);
    for (MouseMotionListener l: this.mouseMotionListeners)
        watchPanel.addMouseMotionListener(l);
    this.updatePositions();
}

private void updatePositions() {
    int count = 0;
    synchronized (this.watches) {
        for (Watch watch: this.watches) {
            if ((this.selectedWatchPanel != null) && (count == this.selectedWatchPanelPosition))
                count++;
            WatchItemPanel panel = this.watchPanels.get(watch);
            if (panel == this.selectedWatchPanel)
                continue;
            panel.setBounds(0, count * WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT, this.getWidth(), WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (this.selectedWatchPanel != null)
        this.selectedWatchPanel.setBounds(0, (this.selectedWatchPanelPosition * WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT) + this.selectedWatchPanelDragOffset, this.getWidth(), WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT);
    this.repaint();
}
```

And here are the `setBounds` methods on `WatchListPanel`:

```
@Override
public void setBounds(Rectangle r) {
    super.setBounds(r);
    for (WatchItemPanel panel: this.watchPanels.values()) {
        panel.setSize(r.width, WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT);
        panel.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    for (WatchItemPanel panel: this.watchPanels.values()) {
        panel.setSize(width, WatchItemPanel.PANEL_HEIGHT);
        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Another piece of information here - all four panels are being painted.  I overrode `paintComponent` in the `WatchItemPanel` and added a `System.out.println` and got this result:

```
WatchItemPanel[,0,66,366x22,invalid,layout=java.awt.GridBagLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777219,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
WatchItemPanel[,0,44,366x22,layout=java.awt.GridBagLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777219,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
WatchItemPanel[,0,22,366x22,layout=java.awt.GridBagLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777219,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
WatchItemPanel[,0,0,366x22,layout=java.awt.GridBagLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777219,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

What's that extra "invalid" column there in the panel?  When I resize the `WatchPanel` the "invalid" goes away.  It looks like an extra column, though.  There's no corresponding non-invalid value on the other lines.  (this is the default `JPanel.toString()` output with the package name removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the component, call `this.revalidate()`.  This causes the container to be marked to re-layout its components.  Once this line of code is added, it works perfectly.